# Bootstrap modal position in WebView UI

Tags: android, bootstrap-4, android-webview, google-chrome-app

Using Bootstrap 4.3.1

On my site, modals work perfectly, in responsive mode too.

I also have an Android app, that among other functions, contains my site in WebView. When I trigger a modal within WebView in the App, on a long page - it opens at the top of the page (not vertically centered) and if you happen to be half scrolled down the page, you will not see it, as the position is fixed to the top, and you now need to scroll UP to see it (if you even know it opened).

Again, in a log web-page, in mobile form - the issue does not exist - only in WebView.
Has anyone run into this?

This is Bootstrap's position for the modal.

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1050;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 0;
}
```

It seems that in WebView, the `position: fixed;` is ignored - as it's relative to the window, so if it scrolls down, the modals goes up with the page.

Tests for this are tricky, as to test properly, you need to test within **an app**, within a WebView Container (as I mentioned, in Chrome responsive on mobile, this issue does not exist).

Comment: Off chance, have you tried  to set  in your style sheet .modal{ position: fixed !important }?

Comment: @Vega - yes, tried that. In Chrome, remote device inspector its indeed showing as `position: fixed`, but in actual fact, on the device itself in the app - i am scrolled half way down the page (https://www.dormi.co.il/users/test222.html) and the modal popup is stuck, to the top of the page, beyond the upper screen where i cannot see it. See image here: https://imgur.com/a/rsYq1QH

Comment: @Vega thanks again for trying. As you can maybe see in the imgur image, the `position: fixed` is indeed being applied (and not over-written). but it seems to be relative to the webview container rather than the app container (the device screen). Which means that it disappears when you scroll. Does this clarify the issue?

Comment: Have you tried to make the body not scrollable while the modal is open?

Comment: @kneidels Have you tried placing the modal html at last in the body tag??

Comment: @Vega - by default, thats the functionality of bootstrap, see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#vertically-centered . the issue is not that, but rather the position of the modal, being relative (or fixed) to the webview container (which might be hidden from view) rather than the actual screen.

Comment: @RahulKhurana - yes, I have tried that. In fact, even this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#vertically-centered - the official sample, the modal does not open properly in the webview setup.

Comment: @kneidels i have tried with https://www.dormi.co.il/users/test222.html link on the android native webview and it is opening the modal at top position.

Comment: can you share your android layout file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to post an update and close this question with an update for anyone who runs into this issue in the future. 
It turned out that there was a bug in the app, and the "pull to refresh" module was interfering with the location of the popups. As soon as that was fixed, the modal opened in its correct position, based on the bootstrap existing code.

Thanks to all those who tried to help.

Comment: Could you please explain more about this? I got same problem.

Comment: @AhmadBudairi - there was a bug in the Android build - it was conflicting with the bootstrap code

Answer (score 0):

Check this below styles are overwriting from some other styles,

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

looks like a style rendering issue,

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work for you.

Put it in html javascript tag.

```
$('#here_put_modal_id').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
   // here are code
   document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0
})
```

Comment: Thanks - this is an interesting work-around, but bad in terms of UI. if i have a popup modal that is context driven (relating to a specific part of the page), i would lose that when the page scrolls up.

Comment: this is just an example you can change the target div like targetemelent. scrollTop = 0

Answer (score -2):

```
.edit-wrap
    z-index 999
    position fixed
    left 0
    right 0
    top 0
    bottom 0
    overflow hidden
    background rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
    display flex
    .edit-container
        background #d1cdb7
        padding 1em 2em 1em 2em
        margin auto
```

This stylus demo works on my webview

Comment: Thanks. The code is not clear. also, can you apply it to the standard bootstrap modal stucture?